# How to fetch metadata from pandas DataMatrix

Tags: python, pandas

I try to use LINCS data(to computing combination of compound by machine learning), but occasionally they formatting in awkward pandas DataFrame (why not simple matrix?). I already learn how fetch other data (gctoo.data_df.iloc[9]) but i need fetch metadata and i am stack at this.
I do this

```
nomy_gctoo.col_metadata_df
```

And get this

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: [REP.A001_A375_24H_X1_B22:A03, REP.A001_A375_24H_X1_B22:A04, REP.A001_A375_24H_X1_B22:A05, REP.A001_A375_24H_X1_B22:A06, REP.A001_A375_24H_X1_B22:A07, REP.A001_A375_24H_X1_B22:A08, REP.A001_A375_24H_X1_B22:A08, ...]
```

How i can get array of index names?

Comment: I think it makes sense to [invest 10-15 minutes to try to understand the beauty of Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html). Trust me - you'll love it as soon as you will start to understand it ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `.index`:

```
arr = nomy_gctoo.col_metadata_df.index

L = nomy_gctoo.col_metadata_df.index.tolist()
```